# Quarkus embedded Derby database connection not possible

Tags: java, derby, quarkus

We have a Quarkus application which needs to connect to an embedded derby database in order to store the application's data. The Derby DB driver in Quarkus is not able to use the provided URL to connect to the database `jdbc:derby:memory:myDB` and we get, at application start, the error message shown below. We encounter the same behaviour for a Derby DB persisted on files.

Our test application is a simple plain Quarkus application with the persistence configured to be an embedded Derby database (see Quarkus project setup below). We would appreciate any hint about what should be changed in the project setup, Quarkus configuration or application's code to have the Quarkus application properly connect to the Derby database.

#### application.properties

```
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=derby
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:derby:memory:myDB
```

#### build.gradle (dependencies)

```
dependencies {
    implementation enforcedPlatform("${quarkusPlatformGroupId}:${quarkusPlatformArtifactId}:${quarkusPlatformVersion}")
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-arc'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy'

    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-hibernate-orm'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-jdbc-derby'

    testImplementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-junit5'
    testImplementation 'io.rest-assured:rest-assured'
}
```

#### gradle.properties

```
quarkusPluginId=io.quarkus
quarkusPluginVersion=2.7.4.Final
quarkusPlatformGroupId=io.quarkus.platform
quarkusPlatformArtifactId=quarkus-bom
quarkusPlatformVersion=2.7.4.Final
```

#### Error message

```
WARN: Datasource '<default>': Driver does not support the provided URL: jdbc:derby:memory:myDB
März 16, 2022 1:25:13 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator initiateService
WARN: HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata
java.sql.SQLException: Driver does not support the provided URL: jdbc:derby:memory:myDB
    at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionFactory.connectionSetup(ConnectionFactory.java:226)
    at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:210)
    at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionPool$CreateConnectionTask.call(ConnectionPool.java:513)
    at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionPool$CreateConnectionTask.call(ConnectionPool.java:494)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at io.agroal.pool.util.PriorityScheduledExecutor.beforeExecute(PriorityScheduledExecutor.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Here the code of the test application

Database.java

```
package test;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;

/**
 *
 */
@ApplicationScoped
public class Database {

    @Inject
    EntityManager mEntityManager;

    @Transactional
    public void createGift(String giftDescription) {
        Gift gift = new Gift();
        gift.setName(giftDescription);
        mEntityManager.persist(gift);
    }

}
```

Gift.java

```
package test;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;

/**
 *
 */
@Entity
public class Gift {
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "giftSeq", sequenceName = "gift_id_seq", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "giftSeq")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

GreetingResource.java

```
package test;

import io.quarkus.runtime.Startup;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Startup
@Path("/hello")
public class GreetingResource {

    @Inject
    Database mDatabase;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello RESTEasy";
    }
}
```

Comment: Modify your property like this and do a try - quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:derby:memory:myDB;create=true , Refer - https://quarkus.io/guides/datasource#derby, db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.7/adminguide/cadminappsclient.html

Comment: We already tried the url `jdbc:derby:memory:myDB;create=true` and it showed the same behaviour. We also tried to connect to a persisted database which we created upfront without any success. We always get the same error message. Thanks anyway for your answer, @Sibin.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Thanks @KotlinIsland for your remark. I have revised the question and also added the test application's code. This is actually a very basic issue: Quarkus being unable to connect to the embedded Derby database, the question would be what is wrong or missing in the application for Quarkus to connect properly to the embedded Derby DB.